# Guiding a Quadrotor Towards a Waypoint

Tags: math, language-agnostic, vector, robotics

I am working on a quadrotor, I know its position (a) I know where I would like to go (b) so what I do is calculate a vector c,

```
c = b - a
c = normalize(c)
```

that gives me a unit vector that will take me to my target. But a quadrotor can move in any direction without rotation so what I have tried to do is rotate that vector c by the robots yaw angle then split it into its x y components and pass them to the robot as roll and pitch angles the problem is when the yaw is 0 degrees (-+ 5) this works but when the yaw is say +90 or -90 it fails and steers to wrong directions. My question is am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Do a search on "Euler angle" or "quaternion" or "rotation matrix" - three solutions to the same problem.  Each has its advantages.

Answer (score 0):

Not doing all the research to be 100% sure of this answer, but it sounds like you are getting a (kind of?) [Gimbal Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock). A solution to this is to use [Quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) as they are not succeptible to Gimbal Lock.